# Display submit button text in lowercase letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When you have a submit button, the text usually defaults to e.g `Create Foo` or `Udate Foo`.

Is it possible to display the same text just in lowercase letters?

E.g, something like this:

`<%= f.submit initial_text.downcase %>`

Is there some way to achieve this, apart from passing strings to the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always set a CSS class to the button that does `text-transform:lowercase;`

`f.submit :class => "lowercase-button"`

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the "Text-Transform: lowercase" CSS style to the button text.